# is mcnemar's test suitable to evaluate the differences of the proportions of events between the subgroups of risk scores?

Tags: biostatistics, paired-data, mcnemar-test, cochran-q, cochran-mantel-haenszel

the authors indicated that comparing event frequencies of events between subgroups( example frs and df) of groups ( low intermediate high) mcnemar's test was used. is it right for this study design[image]?

Comment: Hi, can you rotate the image?